# Prove $\int_{-t}^t f(x) dx =0$ implies $f$ is odd function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f : [−a, a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\int_{-t}^t f(x) dx =0$$ for each $t \in [0, a]$. Show that $f$ is an odd function.

My attempt: Changing variables using $y=-x$, we get $\int_{-t}^t (f(x)+f(-x)) dx =0$.

Now I can not proceed further. Please help.

Comment: If it's true for all $t,$ can you differentiate both sides with respect to $t$?

Comment: Don't you mean $\displaystyle\int_0^t$?

Comment: $$
\int_{ - t}^t {f(x)dx}  = 0 \Leftrightarrow \int_{ - t}^0 {f(x)dx}  + \int_0^t {f(x)dx}  = 0 \Leftrightarrow \int_0^t {f( - y)dy}  + \int_0^t {f(x)dx}  = 0\\ \mathop  \Rightarrow \limits^{\partial _t } f( - t) + f(t) = 0
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$ which is continuous. As you have argued, we have $\int_{-t}^t g(x)dx=0$. Since $g(x)$ is even, this is reduced to $\int_0^t g(x)dx=0$. Since $g(x)$ is continuous, we can differentiate both sides, which shows that $g(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x)$ denote an antiderivative of $f(x).$ By assumptions we have $$F(t)-F(-t)=0,\qquad 0\le t\le a$$ Applying the derivative and the chain rule give
$$f(t)+f(-t)=0$$

Comment: You don't need the primes on the $f$s since $f=F'$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for spotting the misprint